# ExceptionHandler catches AccessDeniedException while using @Order with LOWEST_PRECEDENCE?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have an ExceptionHandler (spring and security 5) which catches all exceptions not caught by other ExceptionHandler, this works nicely:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = BaseBackendController.class)
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
  public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
  }
}
```

But above exceptionhandler also catches AccessDeniedException even though i added the @Order annotation with LOWEST_PRECEDENCE value.

As a temp. solution i added this to the defaultErrorHandler:

```
if(e instanceof AccessDeniedException){
      throw  (AccessDeniedException)e;
    }
```

This works, but i suspect there are many more spring security related exceptions and i rather not add them all to my defaultErrorHandler.

Does anybody know why AccessDeniedException is caught by my ExceptionHandler and not handled by spring security?

Answer (score 0):

You should add another `@ExceptionHandler` for `AccessDeniedException` and then simply re-throw the exception in the handler method. This will propogate `AccessDeniedException` to the Spring Security and it can handle the error.

Comment: Thanks, but this results in the same problems as my temp. solution: you need to know all the spring security related exceptions and write code for them all. This is possible, but is quite difficult to maintain cause what about new exceptions introduced in new versions. Using @Order with LOWEST_PRECEDENCE should work if i understand it right, but it doesn't in my case. I'm just wondering why.

Comment: @Tinus Tate,  you need to dig in to the exception mapping and resolution strategies provided by the auto configuration of the spring security and that way you will get to know if some thing is miss configured or not.